# Devices plugged into monitor headphone jacks aren't recognized

Tags: sound, multiple-monitors, headphones, audio-jack

I have a 3 monitor setup and ubuntu 16.04 duel booted with windows 10. My right monitor has built in speakers as well as a headphone jack, my tower has a headphone jack, and my middle monitor also has a headphone jack. Everything works fine on windows.

On ubuntu, everything works except for the headphone jacks on my monitors. I've tried them with every pair of headphones and speakers I own. Here's what my sound settings show, even with speakers plugged into headphone jacks on a monitor:

[Sound Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7w0Ns.png)

Selecting either of the first two devices plays audio out of my right monitor's built in speakers, and the last option plays sound out of the audio jack on my tower.

I've been googling, fiddling with settings/ports, and testing devices on windows and ubuntu for hours, but with no luck. It's like ubuntu doesn't seem to recognize that the headphone jacks on my monitors exist. Any help would be awesome